# I want to take a screenshot of the size specified by window size in headless(new) mode of selenuim

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-headless

I am currently developing with python, selenium and chrome in headless(new) mode.
Now I want to take a screenshot of a specific size by specifying chrome's window-size.
However, when I actually take the screenshot, it saves an image of a different size.

The source code is written below.

```
options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])
options.add_argument('--headless=new')
options.add_argument("--window-size=800,600")
options.add_argument("--start-fullscreen")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(f"https://www.google.com/")
sleep(1)
print(driver.get_window_size()) #{'width': 800, 'height': 600}
driver.get_screenshot_as_file("./tmp.png")
```

The size of this tmp.png will be 1574 x 1188.
Why the difference in size? And how can I get a screenshot of the size I want?

Comment: I don't know much about seleium, but i removed `new` from the line 

`options.add_argument('--headless=new')` and the code behaved like you just asked.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I didn't mention it here, but the code I really want to do is to take the twitch screen. And I want to press the full screen button and just take the game screen without any extra information. But without the new, pressing the fullscreen button did not respond. That's why I can't remove the new.

Comment: You mean you want to open a "twitch" stream, pressing the full screen button, and take a screenshot ?
If your code is updated can you edit the post and share it again?

Comment: Sorry, but while it is possible to increase the twitch code, I don't think that would be a good idea as it would make the sample code more complex. Also, I believe I can reproduce the problem here on google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried to take ss with using selenium. However, you can use this Pillow to resize your image, and I hope it can be helpful.

```
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open('asdas.JPG')
new_image = image.resize((500, 500))
new_image.save('myimage_500.jpg')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't think this directly solves the problem of different sizes when taking screenshots in chrome's new headless mode. However, the image size ratio seems to be the same as the one specified in window size. So if I can't solve the problem directly, I would like to use this method to solve the problem. Thank you very much.